# Spring RestTemplate performance issue with authentication

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am using Spring RestTemplate to retrieve objects from a restful sever along with a Interceptor for basic authentication. However, I am experiencing huge performance differences between localhost and dev environment.

When running both the client and restful server in local, RestTemplate getForObject takes 3 seconds. When running the client in local and restful server in DEV, it takes 59 seconds. I put some logging in the Interceptor - in DEV, the restful server responds pretty fast (in 1 second). What causes the delay is the getForObject so I guess in DEV RestTemplate takes lots of time to covert the response body to the object.

I make the same call in localhost and DEV so I expect the size of response body to be identical. Does anybody know how to improve the performance in DEV? Many Thanks!

Interceptor:

```
public class BasicAuthInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

public static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(BasicAuthInterceptor.class);

private String username;
private String password;

public BasicAuthInterceptor( String username, String password ) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

@Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution)
        throws IOException {
    //Build the auth-header
    final String auth = username + ":" + password;
    final byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64( auth.getBytes( Charset.forName( "US-ASCII" ) ) );
    final String authHeader = "Basic " + new String( encodedAuth );

    //Add the auth-header
    request.getHeaders().add( "Authorization", authHeader );

    log.info("Sending request to the data server");
    ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
    log.info("Got response from the data server. Status: " + response.getStatusCode() + " " + response.getStatusText());
    log.info("Response header: " + response.getHeaders());

    return response;
} }
```

RestTemplate call:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

            final List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor>();
            interceptors.add( new BasicAuthInterceptor( "user", "xxx" ) );
            restTemplate.setInterceptors( interceptors );

            AggregatedCptyExposure[] expoIq = restTemplate.getForObject(fullUrl, AggregatedCptyExposure[].class);
```

From log, I do notice the response headers are different between DEV and local.

Local:

```
INFO  09/12 13:41:00.160 {} [pool-6-thread-8] BasicAuthInterceptor - Response header: {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Date=[Wed, 12 Sep 2018 17:41:00 GMT]}
```

DEV:

```
INFO  09/12 13:44:05.800 {} [pool-6-thread-13] BasicAuthInterceptor - Response header: {Date=[Wed, 12 Sep 2018 17:44:05 GMT], Set-Cookie=[X-Session-Token=mode&BASICAUTH&user&name&token&AAEAAAFlzuIHW2wljAAXQ5zrkYZFE75H7p9MfbH6REVWICAgICAgIAEnuj5LmEhn8vdL8atZ9j6DGGmXSimKUUSEc%2BpPv6uJ2A%3D%3D; path=/; HttpOnly, ROUTEID=.2; path=/, ROUTEID=.2; path=/, EncryptCookie=!MUIcv63qIjUiv0DaswGZ/7EuVxdhGlpB0wRK4L7mIcd8CeqPrqCaQXDpIomEbw5h3/vRHDvPYFxjQQ==; expires=Wed, 12-Sep-2018 21:44:05 GMT; path=/; Httponly; Secure], Strict-Transport-Security=[max-age=31536000], Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8], Vary=[Accept-Encoding], X-Frame-Options=[SAMEORIGIN], Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only=[default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; report-uri ....], X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], Access-Control-Allow-Origin=[.....], Access-Control-Allow-Credentials=[true], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], X-Route-Ref=[Route:2;dcts01aa/1=dcts03;2=dcts01; P59357], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], Keep-Alive=[timeout=5, max=100], Connection=[Keep-Alive], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked]}
```

Comment: Enable spring debugging to get logging details on why the extractor is taking so long.  Verify the spring jars and its dependencies are the same version between local and DEV.  Also, `RestTemplate` is thread safe and the interceptor appears to be the same for all requests.  Consider making the `RestTemplate`, along with its interceptor, a singleton scoped spring bean to be shared for all requests.

Comment: @AndrewS - thank you for your response! I tried to enable the spring debugging by adding `<logger name="org.springframework"><level value="debug"/></logger>` to my log4j.xml. However, I don't get the logging details of the extractor. Could you please let me know how to properly define the logging for extractor?

Comment: It's likely a one of the dependency jars - for example jackson.